# mach-omap2 (am335x) Where is the frequency table/CPUClock file?

Tags: kernel, beagleboneblack

My main mission here is to compile the kernel removing/adjusting the Max frequency of 1000Mhz to 1200Mhz.

The problem, I cannot find where the frequency table is. Nor a definitive clock.c file to adjust the CPU speed. I'm looking specifically for the Texas Instruments Sitara am3358 SoC, which is in the BeagleBone Black.

Anyone who can point me in the appropriate direction would be most welcomed.

Here is the Kernel source I'm using, the 3.8 Version in particular.
git://github.com/beagleboard/kernel.git

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have the am3359, and in my Technical reference manual it give the address to a register that can adjust the crystal clock. The base address to the control module is 0x44E10000 offset of 0x40. It says the reset value comes from SYSBOOT[15:14]